# Не происходит вывод в консоль по клику (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытался сделать табы на js, но в данном случае не выводит ничего в консоль. Хотел, чтобы при нажатии менялся фон у конкретного элемента, но на стадии проверки функции при клике уже пошло что-то не так

html:

```
<button class="nav-btn active">option_1</button>
<button class="nav-btn">option_2</button>
<button class="nav-btn">option_3</button>
```

css:

```
.nav-btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #2d283e;
}
.nav-btn.active {
  background-color: #3a3350;
}
```

JS:

```
const settingsBtn = document.querySelectorAll("nav-btn")

settingsBtn.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("YOOOOOOOOO")
  })
})
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к элементу `<nav-btn>`, а такого нет.
Проблема о опечатке, ибо забыли точку

```
//                         ⇓
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-btn")
```

Comment: Боже, опять 25, спасибо! А то я опять не заметил бревно в своем глазу

Comment: @bluepuper, не за что, если есть возможность, отметьте мой ответ как правильный.

Comment: Да, конечно, там только через 15 минут после публикации можно это сделать